# Create unique random data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, unique

I want to generate random datasets with regex.

Therefore I have an expression like [a-z]{10}.
I want to generate maybe 200.000 data - maybe more (it should be generic), every data should be unique.

How can i implement that?
at the moment i have a algorithm, that generates a random string, then search in an array that stores the values, if the string is already in there it repeats that process. Otherwise it stores the string in the array.

But when I have 200.000 possible data and I want 200.000 different data, it takes a real long time
1) search the whole array every iteration ...
2) takes a lot of iterations because there are less possibilities to "hit"

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this? Are you just trying to create test data?

Comment: If the array can be sorted, use binary search to insert/find values.

Comment: e.g. [a-z]{7} has ~8.000.000.000 possibilities, does that matter to the binary search? it could be that i don't know how many values i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are searching through the entire array each time you want to store a value.  Have you considered using a [Hash Table](http://vb.net-informations.com/collections/vb.net_HashTable.htm) with a Key/Value pair?

Comment: hi, yes at the moment i do that! :(   -- hmm like a "hash-map" -- e.g. [a-z]{7} has ~8.000.000.000 possibilities, does that matter? :>

Comment: Essentially with a hash table you are storing a key that allows lookups via that key.  If/when you generate the same random value you could then find it much faster than your current method.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you really need is a way of generating 200.000 unique strings of `[a-z]{10}`, followed by a [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: to be really random there would be 26^10 possibilities, should i generate each possibility?

Comment: If you want true randomness among the unique strings, I second @Rob Haupts suggestion of a hash table to keep track of duplicates.